# Can a minifier do this? (....and is it a good idea?)

Tags: javascript, minify

I have a JavaScript application that generates a significant amount of DOM elements. It means that I often use `document.createElement("tagname")` in my script.

I am thinking about using this simple function:

```
function c(e) {return document.createElement(e);}
```

I would keep writing my code in JavaScript (or maybe CoffeScript), and use the full document.createElement method in the code for readability. But I would expect that when I "compile" or minify the code, all the instances of document.createElement are replaced with the `c` function.

I would do the same for other methods: document.getElementById, etc. I am hoping that I can shorten my code by 10 to 20% with this technique.

Are there minifiers or compilers that can do this? And does it make sense in the first place?

Comment: What benefits are you hoping for?

Comment: If nothing else, you could always do this yourself as a "pre-minification" step. Shouldn't be too hard to script.

Comment: Do you gzip your files? I'd bet that it won't make much of a difference in the long run.

Comment: Why not just use `c = document.createElement`? **EDIT:** Nope, that errors. `createElement` must be called from the document object. The closest you can get is `c = document.createElement.bind(document)`

Comment: @Ash: the benefit is a smaller js file (gain of 10 to 20% as I said in the question).

Comment: Creating too may DOM elements? Start using JavaScript templates: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Comment: Usually you gzip your code anyway .. minification IMHO is for projects where every single byte matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it will gain you that much. The uncompressed js file might be quite a bit smaller, but compression should deal with with such a repetitive string. So I expect the gain on a compressed(http gzip compression) javascript file to be rather small.

Comment: I believe the gzipped size with the alias functions will actually be larger, as the alias functions themselves count towards extra bytes...

Answer (score 1):

I just call the function `create(e)` instead of `c(e)`. That way you get the best of both worlds, readability and you don't have to type so much.

Answer (score 0):

Most minifiers will not redefine DOM library functions with shorter versions. However, you see this pattern done by hand in many libraries to reduce and/or simplify code. So there is nothing wrong with doing this yourself. Just make sure that you do it inside a closure....

Take a look at the options for uglifier and see what it can do for you for example:

```
{
  :mangle => true, # Mangle variables names
  :toplevel => false, # Mangle top-level variable names
  :except => [], # Variable names to be excluded from mangling
  :max_line_length => 32 * 1024, # Maximum line length
  :squeeze => true, # Squeeze code resulting in smaller, but less-readable code
  :seqs => true, # Reduce consecutive statements in blocks into single statement
  :dead_code => true, # Remove dead code (e.g. after return)
  :lift_vars => false, # Lift all var declarations at the start of the scope
  :unsafe => false, # Optimizations known to be unsafe in some situations
  :copyright => true, # Show copyright message
  :ascii_only => false, # Encode non-ASCII characters as Unicode code points
  :inline_script => false, # Escape </script
  :quote_keys => false, # Quote keys in object literals
  :beautify => false, # Ouput indented code
  :beautify_options => {
    :indent_level => 4,
    :indent_start => 0,
    :space_colon => false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense, but a minifier that does this automatically has to be smart about a few things:

1. Does the part of the code that's factored out into a new function repeat enough times to make this refactoring more economic?
2. Potential performance hit from wrapping code inside additional functions: Especially when it's code that's used very often in a time-critical scenario (a profiler can tell this, a minifier probably can't). Perhaps the minifier can put a cap on the number of replacements in deeply nested function calls etc.

You're probably better off doing this manually.

Comment: Is there a performance hit if I just do a renaming as Eric suggests: c=document.createElement ?

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on the minifier. **Most do not do this.** For instance the code:

```
window['a'] = document.createElement('div');
window['b'] = document.createElement('div');
window['c'] = document.createElement('div');
```

On Google Closure Compiler advanced mode:

```
window.a=document.createElement("div");window.b=document.createElement("div");window.c=document.createElement("div");
```

On YUI Compressor:

```
window.a=document.createElement("div");window.b=document.createElement("div");window.c=document.createElement("div");
```

On jscompress.com:

```
window["a"]=document.createElement("div");window["b"]=document.createElement("div");window["c"]=document.createElement("div")
```

I imagine that compilers are reluctant to alias DOM methods in case of weird side effects, and also repeated strings in the js will get compressed well by gzip anyway.